# three.js orbitcontrols move shaking

Tags: camera, three.js, move, shake

I´m creating a scene with planets and spaceships moving in a fleet (a group), I´m using orbitcontrols, center on the fleet.

But when fleet is moving (the group), the ships and the fleet start to shaking. Now I Know that is because of the camera but I don´t know how to fix it. The ships are in calm until I rotate the camera.

It´s no depend of the scale of my scene or far/near values:

```
             .1,   // Near
             1e9   // Far
```

I add.camera to the fleet group, but I think is not the problem, is something about the camera buffer or something.

I recorded a video about that where you can see the ships shaking when they are moving:

http://5dim.es/pruebas/shake.mp4

Thanks

Comment: With such a huge far value you basically don't have depth buffer accuracy. Read through http://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html and https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision on why you should consider changing it.

Comment: A lot of thanks!!, I was doing test and the best diferent betwen near and far is 1e6, with this shaking effect stops

Comment: You can also set logarithmic depth buffer, that should be able to handle 1e9 scale

Comment: How can I do a logarithmic depth buffer?